# antialiasing is disabled when using Compositing nodes?

Tags: compositing-nodes, blender-internal-render-engine, antialiasing

I just added a simple compositing node setup to add glare to my scene.
The edges of my cubical objects seem very jagged when enabling nodes while rendering.
I think it might be an antialiasing issue.

I've tried the "Full Sample" mode, but I see no difference.

What's going on?

Comment: Please provide some screenshots to estimate issue.

Comment: Are you using the Z-buffer or the Object ID buffer in some way? These inputs are normally not anti-aliased.